# Calling a sub, except for a few lines

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to call a sub and have the sub run with the exception of a few lines within the sub that is being called?

So for example, I want to call a "master_clear" sub from my "main" sub, but I do not want the master_clear to clear everything; there are some ranges that need to be left.  How can I do this?

Comment: Create a parameter on the `Master_clear` sub, and based on the input only clear all\specific ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an optional parameter.

```
Sub foo(someParam as String, Optional doExtra as Boolean = False)
   'Do stuff

   If doExtra Then
       'Do extra stuff
   End If

   'Do some more stuff
 End Sub

Sub bar
    foo "hello" ' skip extra stuff
    foo "bye", True ' do extra stuff
End Sub
```

[More on Optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164532%28v=office.10%29.aspx)